# Expected value of Truncated Normal Distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, expected-value, truncated-normal-distribution, truncated-distributions

For the truncated normal distribution below:

$$
{f_X(x; σ, a, b)} = \frac{1}{\sigma}\frac{φ(\frac{x-µ}{σ})}{Φ(\frac{b-µ}{σ})-Φ(\frac{a-µ}{σ})}
$$
$$
a = 1; b = ∞; σ = 2
$$

I need to calculate the expected value of X for the general µ and for when µ = 2.

I understand that φ and Φ represent the pdf and CDF of a standard normal distribution random variable.

My first question is, when expanding ${f_X(x; σ, a, b)}$, does it equal to below?

$$
{f_X(x; σ, a, b)} = \frac{1}{\sigma}\frac{φ(\frac{x-µ}{σ})}{Φ(\frac{b-µ}{σ})-Φ(\frac{a-µ}{σ})}
=\frac{1}{\sigma}\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2π}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{b-µ}{σ}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2π}\sigma}e^{-\frac{(x-µ)^2}{2{\sigma^2}}}dx - \int_{-\infty}^{\frac{a-µ}{σ}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2π}\sigma}e^{-\frac{(x-µ)^2}{2{\sigma^2}}}dx } 
=\frac{1}{\sigma}\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2π}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{1 - \int_{-\infty}^{\frac{a-µ}{σ}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2π}\sigma}e^{-\frac{(x-µ)^2}{2{\sigma^2}}}dx }
$$

Question 2a: Can this be simplified further?

Question 2b: Should I be expanding it at all?

The formula for finding the expected value of X is:

$$
E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)dx
$$

Question 3: Should I use this to find the expected value of X? ie.
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\cdot\frac{1}{\sigma}\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2π}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{1 - \int_{-\infty}^{\frac{a-µ}{σ}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2π}\sigma}e^{-\frac{(x-µ)^2}{2{\sigma^2}}} }dx
$$
which seems very complicated.

Question 4: Is there a better way to find the expected value of X?

Apologies if what I am asking is obvious, I am not familiar with using the `φ` and `Φ` concepts. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please [search our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=+is%3Aanswer+score%3A5+trunc*+normal+expec*+-mixture) for more answers.  This only looks complicated because you devote about half the symbols to the trivial task of re-expressing the units of measure.  You can choose units in which $\sigma=1$ and the origin is $\mu=0.$  Everything simplifies greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would provide you a general hint.

What does truncation actually do? For $X\sim f$ having an infinite support, the distribution of $X$ in $(a, b] ,~a,b\in\bar{\mathbb R}$ is $$ \frac{f(x)\cdot\boldsymbol 1_{x\in(a,b]}}{\Pr(a<X\leq b)};$$ the denominator is nothing but $F(b) -F(a). $ When $b=\infty,$ it is $S(a). $

When $X$ is normal, this means we need to evaluate $\mathbb E[X\mid X> a].$

Use $f^\prime(x) =\frac{-(x-\mu) }{\sigma^2}f(x) $ and few simple algebraic manipulations (work with $S$ rather than $F$) to yield $\mu+\sigma^2\frac{f(a) }{S(a) }.$

No need to break the entire pdf in numerator and denominator. Work wisely as it involves nothing but regular calculus procedure and property of normal density.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. Can I ask what is ()? is it the normal pdf? Isn't it 0 if so? Sorry I'm confused.

Comment: It's the density evaluated at $x=a.$

Comment: Sorry do you mean cumulative density? Isn't that F(a)?

Comment: No, I meant the pdf. After standardisation of $a, $ you can use $\varphi.$